# SQL Query - Get count of two columns from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table 1:

```
TicketNumber    | Rules
---------------------------
PR123       | rule_123
PR123       | rule_234
PR123       | rule_456
PR999       | rule_abc
PR999       | rule_xyz
```

---

Table2:

```
TicketNumber    | Rules
---------------------------
PR123       | rule_123
PR123       | rule_234
PR999       | rule_abc
```

NOTE: Both tables have the same structure: same column names but different count.

NOTE: Both tables have same set of TicketNumber values

CASE 1:
If I need ticket and rules count of each ticket from table1, the query is:

```
Select [TicketNo], COUNT([TicketNo]) AS Rules_Count from [Table1] group by TicketNo
```

This will give me output in format :

```
ticketNumber    | Rules_Count
---------------------------
PR123       | 3
PR999       | 9
```

---

CASE 2:  (NEED HELP WITH THIS)

Now, the previous query gets the ticket and the count of the ticket of only 1 table. I need the count of the same ticket (since both have same set of tkt nos) in table2 also.

I need result in this way:

```
ticketNumber    | Count(ticketNumber) of table1 | Count(ticketNumber) of table2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PR123       | 3                 | 2
PR999       | 2                 | 1
```

Both Table1 and table2 have the same set of ticket nos but different counts

How do i get the result as shown above?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the syntax suggests SQL Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler solution from a "statement point of view" (without `COALESCE` that maybe it's not so easy to understand).

Pay attention to the performances:

```
Select T1.TicketNumber,T1.Rules_Count_1,T2.Rules_Count_2
FROM
(
  Select [TicketNumber], COUNT([TicketNumber]) AS Rules_Count_1 
  from [Table1] T1
  group by TicketNumber) T1
INNER JOIN
(
  Select [TicketNumber], COUNT([TicketNumber]) AS Rules_Count_2
  from [Table2] T2
  group by TicketNumber
 ) T2
on T1.TicketNumber = T2.TicketNumber
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/23d4a/3)

Comment: HOwever, InnerJoin means that the count(table1) should be > than count(table2) right? What if its different?

Comment: Inner join means "keep only the rows present in both the tables and join them". Thus, if you put a row with TicketNumberX in Table1 and 42 rows with TicketNumberX in Table2 it should work the same way. But if you put 0 rows with TicketNumberX in Table2 you'll never get a join.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to do this without using JOINS?

Comment: Yes but it's not a good idea due to intensive filtering by WHERE clause and UNION in place of a simple JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `full outer join` after aggregation (or an inner join if you really know that both tables have the same tickets:

```
select coalesce(t1.TicketNo, t2.TicketNo) as TicketNo,
       coalesce(t1.Rules_Count, 0) as t1_Rules_Count,
       coalesce(t2.Rules_Count, 0) as t2_Rules_Count
from (Select [TicketNo], COUNT([TicketNo]) AS Rules_Count
      from [Table1]
      group by TicketNo
     ) t1 full outer join
     (Select [TicketNo], COUNT([TicketNo]) AS Rules_Count
      from [Table2]
      group by TicketNo
     ) t2
     on t1.TicketNo = t2.TicketNo;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Your query works perfectly.However, outer join means that table2 should contain more count than table1 right? What to do if the counts vary?

Comment: @sabz . . . A full outer join returns all the rows from both tables.  You may be thinking of a `left outer join` or `right outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.center,
       A.total_1st,
       B.total_2nd
FROM   (SELECT a.center,
               Count (a.dose1) AS Total_1st
        FROM   table_1 a
        GROUP  BY a.center) A
       INNER JOIN (SELECT b.center,
                          Count (b.dose2) AS Total_2nd
                   FROM   table_2 b
                   GROUP  BY b.center) B
               ON a.center = b.center
ORDER  BY A.center
```